# Why vscode does not know Notification.permission in typescript?

Tags: typescript, notifications, visual-studio-code

In vscode, when I type `Notification.permission` in TypeScript, the vscode always tells me there occur an error:

```
Property 'permission' does not exist on type '{ new (title: string, options?: NotificationOptions | undefined): Notification; prototype: Notifi...'.
```

It seems that vscode does not know there is a property calls `permission` in `Notification`? Why, and what can I do to fix it?

---

UPDATED: I tried `npm install @types/chrome --save-dev`, nothing changed.

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14701

Comment: thanks, but i still don't understand what can i do ...

Comment: i tried to add `"es6"` in `compilerOptions.lib` in tsconfig.json, but nothing changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed as of TypeScript v3. It transpiles correctly when using Notification.permission

Answer (score 1):

As indicated in [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14701), Typescript's built-in typings for `Notification` are currently inaccurate.

Until that is fixed, you'll need to access `Notification.permission` using a more forceful approach:

```
const p: string = Notification['permission'];

console.log(p);
```

Comment: LGTM, it work exactly what i want (although it seems ugly)

Comment: it's 2018, and they still haven't fixed it with typescript 2.8

Comment: @NullVoxPopuli It was 2018 when the question above was posted. Looks like the fix has been made and it is slated for release in TS 3.0: https://github.com/Microsoft/TSJS-lib-generator/pull/438

Answer (score -1):

this property isn't static so you have to create a notification *instance*:

```
const n = new Notification("asd");
console.log(n.permission);
```

Comment: `Notification.permission` _is_ static.

Comment: My bad. Just assumed from the typings :)